# How to use Solr MinHashQParser

Tags: solr, similarity, minhash

Currently I'm trying to integrate Jaccard similarity search using MinHash and I stumbled upon solr's 8.11 [MinHash Query Parser](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/other-parsers.html#minhash-query-parser) and it says in the docs:

> The queries measure Jaccard similarity between the query string and MinHash fields

How to correctly implement it?

As docs say, I added `<fieldType>` and `<field>` like so:

```
<field name="min_hash_analysed" type="text_min_hash" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="false" />

<fieldType name="text_min_hash" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="5" outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" maxShingleSize="5" tokenSeparator=" "/>
            <filter class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.minhash.MinHashFilterFactory" bucketCount="512" hashSetSize="1" hashCount="1"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I tired saving some text to that new `min_hash_analysed` field and then trying to query very similar text using query provided in the doc.

```
{!min_hash field="min_hash_analysed" sim="0.5" tp="0.5"}Very similar text to already saved document text
```

I was hoping to get back all documents that have higher similarity score than `sim="0.5"`, but no matter what I get `"numFound":0`

[image: Solr query result]

Surely I'm doing some thing wrong. How should I correctly integrate **Solr's MinHash Query Parser**?

Comment: According to the response it seems you're sending `{!min_hash field..}` directly as a separate parameter, not as a query in the `q=` parameter. `q={!min_hash ..}query text here` would be the correct syntax in the URL.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you. You were correct. I misunderstood how to use the *Raw Query Parameters* field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the response it seems you're sending `{!min_hash field..}` directly as a query parameter, not as a *Solr query* as given by the the `q=` parameter.

```
q={!min_hash ..}query text here
```

.. would be the correct syntax in the URL (and apply URL escaping as required).